# Typecasting between derived and base for vector iterations : C2664 error

Tags: c++, vector, type-conversion, radix, derived-class

I have the following functions

```
void DrawAndShowCircle(int windowWidth, int windowHeight,int windowType,Scalar windowBGColor, VirtualCircle circle)
    {
        cv::circle(circleImage,circle.Center,circle.Radius,circle.Color,circle.Thickness,circle.LineType);
    }

void DrawAndShowCircles(int windowWidth, int windowHeight,int windowType,Scalar windowBGColor, vector<VirtualObject> circles)
    {
        circleImage = Mat(windowHeight,windowWidth,windowType);
        circleImage.setTo(windowBGColor);

        for(vector<VirtualObject>::iterator it = circles.begin(); it != circles.end(); ++it)
        {
            DrawAndShowCircle(windowWidth,windowHeight,windowType,windowBGColor,*it);
        }
        imshow("circle",circleImage);
        cvWaitKey(0);       
    }
```

What I have as problem is that in DrawAndShowCircles I am stuck at understanding the type casting, at the point where I use a for loop to traverse the objects.

I have base class  `VirtualObject` which is inherited by `VirtualCircle`

I am trying to traverse a vector and show the circles. This is being done for OpenCV so you will find some OpenCV functions.

Here is the calling code

```
 vector<VirtualObject> circles;
   circles.push_back(VirtualCircle(Point(100,50),15,2,Scalar(255,100,100),1));
   circles.push_back(VirtualCircle(Point(100,100),25,2,Scalar(100,255,100),1));
   circles.push_back(VirtualCircle(Point(100,150),35,2,Scalar(100,100,255),1));
   DrawAndShowCircles(200,200,CV_8UC3,Scalar(255,255,255),circles);
```

I am unable to traverse using the for loop. The type-casting is not clear to me. Please advise.

Comment: Use pointers or you'll get object slicing.

Comment: you mean pointers for the vectors? vector<virtualobjects*> ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By storing `VirtualObject` instances (instead of pointers) in your vector, you have caused [slicing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing) to occur. This means that your vector does **not hold any circles at all**.

When you change that, you run into the issue that the conversion from `VirtualCircle*` to `VirtualObject*` can be done automatically (because any `VirtualCircle` instance is also always a `VirtualObject` instance), but the reverse requires an explicit cast, because the compiler can't be sure that it is always safe to interpret a `VirtualObject` as a `VirtualCircle`. The cast you need here is a [`dynamic_cast`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_cast).

And even better than `dynamic_cast` would be to change your design to use virtual functions. They were designed exactly for situations like this.